# ERB files rendering inside stackprof report

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling, erb

I'm working on the project written in Ruby On Rails and use stackprof for profiling. The problem is that some of my methods are called from ERB files. And their rendering isn't called directly from the controller action.
How can I include all of them in my stackprof report to be able to compare time taken for both rendering and controller action methods?

I'm using basic flow described in the [stackprof readme file](https://github.com/tmm1/stackprof) for controller action:

```
StackProf.run(mode: :cpu, out: 'tmp/stackprof-cpu-myapp.dump') do
  #...
end
```